# how to add a field in wireless trace format in ns2?

Tags: networking, simulation, trace, ns2, energy

I'm working to add a field in the existing energy format in ns2.
the default format is like `[energy 999.899140 ei 0.100 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.001]`. I would like to add another field **Erel** in the existing format like `[energy 999.899140 ei 0.100 es 0.000 et 0.000 er 0.001` **erel with its value**].
I added functions and calculating methods of **erel** in the `energy-model.cc and .f files` and in the `cmu-trace.cc and .h` files.
after executing `make` it doesn't shows any error; even though I didn't find the added variable in the trace output.

anybody working on tracing in ns2? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

successfully added a field in the wireless trace file format. 
After modification/addition of methods, classes, files, functions .... etc. 
the make should be executed as,
`$ make clean $ make $ make install` 
then, it compiles all modified/added values/fns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some entries are required in ns-2.35/tcl/lib/ns-* ? Not sure the "fprint" entries you have done in [file].cc can stand alone.

E.g. ns-lib.tcl : The default entry is shown here ...

```
  1384  # If exists a traceAllFile_, print $str to $traceAllFile_
  1385  Simulator instproc puts-ns-traceall { str } {
  1386      $self instvar traceAllFile_
  1387      if [info exists traceAllFile_] {
  1388          puts $traceAllFile_ $str
  1389      }
  1390  }
```

Energy :

```
$ grep -n energy *                                 
ns-lib.tcl:323:#                  -energyModel    "EnergyModel"
ns-lib.tcl:357:Simulator instproc energyModel  {val} { $self set energyModel_  $val }                                                             
ns-lib.tcl:607:     energyModel_ initialEnergy_ txPower_ rxPower_ \
ns-lib.tcl:736: if [info exists energyModel_] {
ns-lib.tcl:747:         $node addenergymodel [new $energyModel_ $node \
ns-lib.tcl:1292:Simulator instproc energy-color-change {level1 level2} {
ns-lib.tcl:1341:        $self instvar energyModel_ 
ns-lib.tcl:1343:        if [info exists energyModel_] {
```